# How to get access_token from LinkedIn AIP?

Tags: api, linkedin-api

I used OAuth 2.0 Client Credentials Flow (2-Legged) to get access token and I followed each step as described in https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/v2/oauth2-client-credentials-flow. 
But when I send the API request to get access token I received following response

```
{
    "error": "access_denied",
    "error_description": "This application is not allowed to create application tokens"
}
```

Comment: Can you give more details about the HTTP request you are trying to perform?

Answer (score 0):

https://medium.com/@ellesmuse/how-to-get-a-linkedin-access-token-a53f9b62f0ce

you may check this way to get linkedin  access token

Comment: This is Member Authorization. Not what I want.

Comment: This seems to be a 3-legged flow example but 
did you have any luck getting 2-legged OAuth authentication work for LinkedIn? I have added all the products that I could for my app including the Marketing Developer Platform in the dashboard and I am still unable to get an application token. I am following this doc learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/authentication/